# Settings for Smooth Streaming paranoid CPU heuristics

Tags: silverlight, smooth-streaming-player, smooth-streaming

I want my Smooth Streaming video to play very well on low-end devices. However, the default settings seem very optimistic and continuously retry to play a too-high quality level, resulting in a very bad playback experience.

I know that the Silverlight Smooth Streaming media engine is fairly configurable. At the moment, I can only go at it with trial and error. Therefore, I figured I should ask for existing knowledge. Does anyone have any recommendations for me on this front - what sort of configuration to use?

My goal is to make the CPU heuristics very paranoid, so it will rarely try to upgrade the quality level. Even if it does, it should only upgrade by one step (however, I am not sure if there's any setting for that... it appears to upgrade in very large jumps right now - occasionally from 500 kbps straight to 3 mbps).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to http://forums.iis.net/t/1172146.aspx to get an idea of which settings can be tweaked.

Thanks,
Ez.

http://blogs.southworks.net/ejadib